# vue3 global variable change value on the fly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vite

I have a problem in my vue3 project that the global variable doesnt change its value in template

**main.js**

```
import router from './router'
import { createMetaManager } from 'vue-meta'
import i18n from './assets/js/i18n.js'
import App from './App.vue'
import { reactive } from 'vue'

import './assets/js/app.js'
import './assets/styles/app.scss'


const app = createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(i18n)
  .use(createMetaManager())

app.config.globalProperties.$test = reactive({ id: 1, name: 'test' })

app.mount('#app')
```

and then i try to access global variable **$test** in component this way:

```
<template>
    <template v-if='$test.id'>{{ $test }}</template>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' @click='set'>change</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' @click='reset'>reset</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' @click='update'>update</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        set() {
            this.$test = { id: 3, name: 'user3' }
            console.log(this.$test)
        },
        reset() {
            this.$test = []
            console.log(this.$test)
        },
        update() {
            this.$test.name = 'updated name'
            console.log(this.$test)
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$test = { id: 2, name: 'user' }
        console.log(this.$test)
    }
}
</script>
```

So when i go to the page i can see in browser console that global variable actually changes
[image]

but in the template its always the same (as i did set in main.js)
[image]

So my question is how to make global variable change on fly in template?

In future it should be an $user object, so when user login, i need to fill that $user object with data, and when user logout i want to make the object empty like `this.$user = []`, and in template show to user or *login/register link* or *go to profile link* through v-if v-else, something like:

```
<tempalte>
    <a href='/profile' v-if='$user.id'>Profile</a>
    <a href='/register' v-else'>Register</a>
</template>
```

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a reactive object to another object, you dropped its reactive property. You should use `ref` in this situation:

```js
app.config.globalProperties.$test = ref({ id: 1, name: 'test' })
...
set() {
    this.$test.value = { id: 3, name: 'user3' }
    console.log(this.$test.value)
},
reset() {
    this.$test.value = []
    console.log(this.$test.value)
},
update() {
    this.$test.value.name = 'updated name'
    console.log(this.$test.value)
},
```

Btw, I don't know the reason you use a global variable but the recommended way is using state management like [pinia](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#pinia)